# Combining Rows with several constraints

Tags: sql, sql-server-2014

My goal here is to combine the joint name, `type 1 (Ex.1)`, to its primary account `(Ex.2)`. This should be done for each share. 
Should I be creating a temporary table to merge them into? I'm using `SQL Server 2014`

[image: Ex.1]
[image: Ex.2]

Comment: Do you just want to return the result set, combined, to a report or a file or something? Then it is best to use a query. A temp table will become static as soon as you populate it. Let me know some more details on what you want to do with the data and I can help with suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
select t1.account,
       t1.primename,
       t2.primename,
       t1.shareid,
       t1.sharedesc
from table t1
left join table t2 on t1.account = t2.account and 
                      t1.shareid = t2.shareid and 
                      t1.nametype = 0 and 
                      t2.nametype = 1
where t1.nametype = 0
```

Answer (score 0):

To get your data, you'll need a query similar to this one. I'm guessing at the keys on your table, though.

```
SELECT 
    Ex1.*, Ex2.JointName
FROM
    Ex1 LEFT JOIN Ex2 ON Ex1.Account = Ex2.Account 
        AND Ex1.ShareDesc = Ex2.ShareDesc 
        AND Ex1.ShareID = Ex2.ShareID 
        AND Ex1.NameDesc = 'Joint'
```

This will return a result set that you can use where you need to. You can wrap this in a view, which will then act like a table and always be up to date, if you need to.